# Is there any english language grammar set in Speech Recognition in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition

I am developing Windows Phone 8 app using c#/xaml.
I am basically trying to convert voice to text and store it in textbox.
The voice input will be normal english.
But for that I need to create whole grammar file i guess.
Is there anything ready made or am i missing something.
Please help

```
private async void record_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Begin recognition using the default grammar and store the result.
        SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await recoWithUI.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
        recoWithUI.Recognizer.Grammars.AddGrammarFromPredefinedType("message", SpeechPredefinedGrammar.Dictation);
        await this.recoWithUI.Recognizer.PreloadGrammarsAsync(); 

        // Check that a result was obtained
        if (recoResult.RecognitionResult != null)
        {
            // Determine if the user wants to save the note.
            var result = MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Heard you say \"{0}\" Save?", recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            // Save the result to the Azure Mobile Service DB if the user is satisfied.
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                voicetext.Text = recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't [load *any* grammars into the recognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206964%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), you get the predefined short message dictation grammar.

```
  // Load the pre-defined dictation grammar by default
  // and start recognition.
  SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await recoWithUI.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

  // Do something with the recognition result
  MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You said {0}.", recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know exactly what you are searching, but maybe this helps you: http://msicc.cloudapp.net/?p=3787

Comment: hello,
See in the above link we have to add grammar so that when a specific word is said, a command execute....I dont want that....i just want to feed everything user says into a textbox...

Comment: Then Eric Brown's answer is your solution :)